# Probability of being in the kth place

Tags: real-analysis, probability, order-statistics

Suppose we have $N$ indenpendent normal random variables, $X_1, \ldots, X_N$. Suppose $X_i \sim N(0, \sigma_i^2)$ for all $i$. Suppose $X_{(k)}$ is the $k$th order statistic. Then what is $Pr(X_i = X_{(k)})$? In other words, what is the probability that $X_i$ is in the $k$th place from the lowest to the highest of these random variables?

Comment: In the case that $\sigma_i$ is the same for all $i$, the probability would simply be $\frac{1}{N}$ in every case.  It should be plain to see that each of the $N!$ orders are equally likely to occur in that case.  In the case that $\sigma_i$ might vary, then consider an extreme case where $\sigma_1=10^{100}$ while $\sigma_i=1$ for each other $i$.  You'd have $X_1$ is far more likely to be either first or last place than somewhere in the middle so the formula will not be the same.  I doubt that a nice convenient formula can be written for the general case where $\sigma_i$ can vary.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks! Yes, with iid distributions, we will just have uniform distribution. My interest is exactly when they have different variances. I am even considering a special case where $N = 2$ and $\sigma_1 > \sigma_2$. I am wondering if $X_1$ is more likely to be larger one?

Comment: For the special case of $N=2$, it should still be uniformly distributed (*you can use calculus to prove this*), but once you reach $N=3$ my example in my first comment should be enough to convince you that the larger the variance for a specific RV the higher the probability that it is in one of the extreme positions in the order and it is no longer uniform.